# Bound eigenvector norm in subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix, and consider some rectangular operator $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, for $m<n$. Then any eigenvector $v$ and associated eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ can be decomposed by the fundamental theorem of linear algebra as $v = v^{(i)} + v^{(k)}$, for $v^{(i)}\in \text{Im}(AP), v^{(k)}\in\ker(P^TA)$. I feel like I should be able to put some upper bound on $\|Av^{(i)}\|_0^2 \leq ...$, in terms of $\lambda, \|v\|_0^2$, but I can't find one. The key is that I don't want $A$ in the bound.

Any ideas are appreciated. Not sure if I am missing something, or if this is actually pretty tricky or not possible.

Comment: Does SPD stand for positive semi-definite?

Comment: Symmetric positive definite